# Can not install Tessera

Tags: private-blockchain, quorum, installation

I have tried everything written in the Tessera GitHub, but I couldn't install it in any way. In the repo it says that there must be an bin folder and we should use the tessera inside it. However, there isn't a bin folder, even after building with gradlew. Anybody encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker run quorumengineering/tessera:latest help` and `docker run quorumengineering/tessera:latest version` on your command prompt. It should be working now. (Make sure to have docker installed)